# Using the WHERE clause in conjunction with NATURAL JOIN SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am reading a book on SQL and I am stuck on an example which is related to a database schema as shown below in the image. [image: THE DATABASE SCHEMA]

The example below solves the query as stated in the book :

Suppose we wish to answer the query “List the names of instructors
along with the titles of courses that they teach.” The query can be written in
SQL as follows:

```
select name , title
from instructor natural join teaches , course
where teaches.course id = course.course id;
```

Now the book states that

" Note that teaches.course id
in the where clause refers to the course id field of the natural join result, since this field in turn came from the teaches relation. "

Again the book states in BOLD that :

"It is not possible to use attribute names containing the original relation names, for instance instructor.name or teaches.course id, to refer to attributes in the natural join result; we can, however, use attribute names such as
name and course id, without the relation names."

(Refering to the query above)If it is not possible then how come the author was able to write the query as

```
teaches.course id = course.course id
```

How can teaches.course refer to the natural join attribute "Course" , the author has so ambiguously put forth his arguments.Please explain me the author's point of view.

Comment: SQL Server does not support `NATURAL JOIN`, so the question cannot be about that database.

Comment: The question is general about the sql language not about sql server. I have just used it as an additional tag .

Comment: `from instructor natural join teaches , course` I'd say: burn the book! `natural join` is generally considered evil, and in combination with the old-style commalis it is beyond recognition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ignore what the book has to say about `NATURAL JOIN`.  Just avoid it.  `NATURAL JOIN` is a bug waiting to happen.  Why?  The join keys are defined simply by naming conventions on columns in the tables -- any columns that happen to have the same names are used.  In fact, `NATURAL JOIN` *ignores* properly defined `FOREIGN KEY` relationships; and they hide the keys actually used for matching.

So, be explicit and use the `ON` or `USING` clauses instead.  These are explicit about the keys being used and the code is more understandable and maintainable.

Then, follow a simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause; *always* use explicit `JOIN` syntax.

So, a good way to write your query would be something like this:

```
select i.name, c.title
from instructor i inner join
     teaches t
     on t.instructor_id = i.instructor_id inner join
     course c
     on t.course_id = i.course_id;
```

Note that there is no `where` clause and all the columns are qualified, meaning that they specify the table they are coming from.

Also, I don't see an `instructor_id` column in the `teaches` table, so this is just an example of what reasonable code would look like.